# How do I turn off the multi-edit tabs in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

A picture is worth 1,000 words.  I'm trying to turn off the following tabs in `IntelliJ` (15.0.6).  In fact, I'd like to disable that entire bar if I can.

Thanks.

[image: Mult-Edit tabs]

Comment: This is probably the 'fault' of one of the plugins you installed - try disabling the ones you don't really need.

Comment: Turned off any and all I can think of that I don't need.  It didn't work.  I don't remember seeing that tab in the past so I'm not actually sure when it first appeared.

Comment: What is the file type?

Comment: @EngineerDollery every file type I normally use.  `.java`, `.js`, `.properties`, etc.

Comment: That's weird then. I have seen these tabs when a document has a rendered view, like with html or md documents, but not on plain text source. It has to be a weird plugin. Is it possible to uninstall and reinstall idea?